# Prevent NSDocument from being created when application gets active

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsdocument

When a document based application becomes active, and there are no open windows, a new document window is automatically created. I want to prevent this behavior and show my *"Choose a Template"* dialog instead of creating a blank document by default.

As you can see on the screenshot, the new document is created somewhere in `NSApplicationMain`.

[image]

How can I prevent this and show my window instead?

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer myself, I was just looking in the wrong place. The creation of untitled documents is handled in the application delegate, so returning `false` from

```
func applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile(sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
  return false
}
```

did the trick.